# Can I write a script that automatically toggles my Wifi band (2.4 or 5 Ghz) based on available networks?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, script

I have a 15" Surfacebook2 (with fully updated Windows 10 as of 7/25/2021). The network card doesn't allow you to "prefer" a band...it just has "auto", "2.4 Ghz only" and "5 Ghz Only" as options:

[image: Marvel AVASTAR Wireless-AC Options in Surfacebook2]

The trouble is, when I'm up in the mountains where I live, I have to use my iPhone's hotspot sharing (which uses the 2.4Ghz band for clients), and when I go to the library to do work, if I leave it on "auto" it will connected to the slower 2.4Ghz band about 90% of the time. I can only reliably connect via 5 Ghz if I force the card to "5 Ghz only" (which is 10 times faster at the library than 2.4 Ghz).

Yes, I can manually toggle this each time...but it's a PIA...and I'm a programmer so I'm always looking for a way to automate things...I just haven't done any scripting in Windows before...

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can automate this somehow?

Comment: Just for everyone else to clarify things, if you set it to auto and you are at the library where the same SSID gives out 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz, it connects you to 2.4Ghz, and that is what you want to avoid?

Comment: @LPChip I just updated my question with that clarification (thanks for the suggestion). Yes, if I leave it on "auto", I will almost always connect to 2.4Ghz at the library...which is 10 times slower.